# div width fit to its content and overflow its parent

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this html:

```
<div class="parent_container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://mountainguides.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Illinizas-photo-ty-gimenez.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://mountainguides.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/IMG_0700.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make `div: item` line up in one row and `div: container` width will auto resize to fit its children. I don't know the number of `div: item` so I can't specific width for `div: container`.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trongcuong1710/cDqSj/4/

Comment: div.item -> inline-block?

Comment: That doesn't work. I searched google for solution and none of them seem to work, including your solution

Comment: is 200px a set width for .parent_container as in your example?

Comment: Yes, .parent_container have a fixed width. And .container will overflow .parent_container if neccessary

Comment: @Sergio I updated my jsfiddle, please take a look again. It made mistake last time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.container {
position:absolute;
float:left;
width: 100%;
min-width:1px;
}
```

Is [this (jsfiddle.net/cDqSj/7/)](http://jsfiddle.net/cDqSj/7/) what you want?